# Question about Replacements and String Manipulations

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I'm trying to get better at *Mathematica* and in the book I'm using (by **Nancy Blachman**) is the following question (which apparently was taken from another book: ***The Art and Science of C***) which reads:

On a standard telephone keypad, the digits are mapped onto the alphabet (minus the letters Q and Z) 
as shown below:

```
        ABC     DEF
 1       2       3
GHI     JKL     MNO
 4       5       6
PRS     TUV     WXY
 7       8       9
```

Write a function `phoneSpell` that generates all possible letter combinations that correspond to a given 
number, represented as a string of digits. For example, if you call `phoneSpell[652]`, your function 
should generate the 27 possible letter combinations corresponding to that prefix, namely

```
{"MJA", "MJB", "MJC", "MKA", "MKB", "MKC", "MLA", "MLB", "MLC", 
"NJA", "NJB", "NJC", "NKA", "NKB", "NKC", "NLA", "NLB", "NLC", "OJA",
"OJB", "OJC", "OKA", "OKB", "OKC", "OLA", "OLB", "OLC"}
```

Note that if the argument passed to `phoneSpell` contains a 0 or 1, that position in the output should 
simply be displayed as that digit, since there are no letters that correspond to it.

I've tried various things like first converting the number to a `String` using `ToString` and getting the `Length` using `StringLength`. I've tried a combination of `Outer` and `Tuples` to get the different combinations, but I'm not getting much luck. Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that does what you want:

```
phoneSpell[n_Integer] := With[{k = StringLength@ToString@n, v = IntegerDigits@n, 
   r = {0 -> "0", 1 -> "1", 2 -> "ABC", 3 -> "DEF", 4 -> "GHI", 
     5 -> "JKL", 6 -> "MNO", 7 -> "PRS", 8 -> "TUV", 9 -> "WXY"}}, 
  StringJoin @@@ Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Characters[v /. r]], k - 1]]
```

Then:

```
phoneSpell[652]
```

> ```
> {"MJA", "MJB", "MJC", "MKA", "MKB", "MKC", "MLA", "MLB", "MLC", "NJA", 
>  "NJB", "NJC", "NKA", "NKB", "NKC", "NLA", "NLB", "NLC", "OJA", "OJB", 
>  "OJC", "OKA", "OKB", "OKC", "OLA", "OLB", "OLC"}
> ```

```
phoneSpell[650231]
```

> ```
> {"MJ0AD1", "MJ0AE1", "MJ0AF1", "MJ0BD1", "MJ0BE1", "MJ0BF1", 
> "MJ0CD1", "MJ0CE1", "MJ0CF1", "MK0AD1", "MK0AE1", "MK0AF1", "MK0BD1", 
> "MK0BE1", "MK0BF1", "MK0CD1", "MK0CE1", "MK0CF1", "ML0AD1", "ML0AE1", 
> "ML0AF1", "ML0BD1", "ML0BE1", "ML0BF1", "ML0CD1", "ML0CE1", "ML0CF1", 
> "NJ0AD1", "NJ0AE1", "NJ0AF1", "NJ0BD1", "NJ0BE1", "NJ0BF1", "NJ0CD1", 
> "NJ0CE1", "NJ0CF1", "NK0AD1", "NK0AE1", "NK0AF1", "NK0BD1", "NK0BE1", 
> "NK0BF1", "NK0CD1", "NK0CE1", "NK0CF1", "NL0AD1", "NL0AE1", "NL0AF1", 
> "NL0BD1", "NL0BE1", "NL0BF1", "NL0CD1", "NL0CE1", "NL0CF1", "OJ0AD1", 
> "OJ0AE1", "OJ0AF1", "OJ0BD1", "OJ0BE1", "OJ0BF1", "OJ0CD1", "OJ0CE1", 
> "OJ0CF1", "OK0AD1", "OK0AE1", "OK0AF1", "OK0BD1", "OK0BE1", "OK0BF1", 
> "OK0CD1", "OK0CE1", "OK0CF1", "OL0AD1", "OL0AE1", "OL0AF1", "OL0BD1", 
> "OL0BE1", "OL0BF1", "OL0CD1", "OL0CE1", "OL0CF1"}
> ```

There's also this slight variation of the above solution:

```
phoneSpell2[n_Integer] := With[{k = Length@(v = Characters@ToString@n), 
   r = {"2" -> "ABC", "3" -> "DEF", "4" -> "GHI", "5" -> "JKL", 
     "6" -> "MNO", "7" -> "PRS", "8" -> "TUV", "9" -> "WXY"}}, 
  StringJoin @@@ Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Characters[v /. r]], k - 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

borrowing rules from RunnyKine

```
r = {0 -> "0", 1 -> "1", 2 -> "ABC", 3 -> "DEF", 4 -> "GHI", 
   5 -> "JKL", 6 -> "MNO", 7 -> "PRS", 8 -> "TUV", 9 -> "WXY"};


n = 652;
StringJoin @@@ Tuples[Characters /@ IntegerDigits@n /. r]


(*{"MJA", "MJB", "MJC", "MKA", "MKB", "MKC", "MLA", "MLB", "MLC", 
"NJA", "NJB", "NJC", "NKA", "NKB", "NKC", "NLA", "NLB", "NLC", "OJA", 
"OJB", "OJC", "OKA", "OKB", "OKC", "OLA", "OLB", "OLC"}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight modifications of existing answers of @RunnyKine and @Algohi (thanks guys!)

```
numRules = 
 MapThread[
  Rule, {Range[1, 9], {{"1"}}~
    Join~(Partition[CharacterRange["A", "Y"] // DeleteCases[#, "Q"] &,
       3])}]
(* {1 -> {"1"}, 2 -> {"A", "B", "C"}, 3 -> {"D", "E", "F"}, 
 4 -> {"G", "H", "I"}, 5 -> {"J", "K", "L"}, 6 -> {"M", "N", "O"}, 
 7 -> {"P", "R", "S"}, 8 -> {"T", "U", "V"}, 9 -> {"W", "X", "Y"}} *)



Clear[phoneSpell]
phoneSpell[n_Integer] := Module[{splitByZero, numToChar, joinedChar},
  splitByZero = 
   DeleteCases[SplitBy[IntegerDigits[n], (# == 0 &)], {0 ..}];
  FromDigits /@ splitByZero;
  numToChar = Tuples /@ (splitByZero /. numRules);
  joinedChar = {FromDigits /@ splitByZero, 
     Map[StringJoin, numToChar, {2}]} // Transpose
  ]

phoneSpell[6520123] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Test to see if a dialed number matches any words in the dictionary**

```
Clear[numDictQ]
numDictQ[n_Integer] := {phoneSpell[n][[All, 
    1]], (Select[#1, ! DictionaryLookup[ToLowerCase[#1]] == {} &] &) /@
     phoneSpell[n][[All, 2]]} // Transpose

numDictQ[78225039242643] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Test to see if a string of letters, if dialed, will match any other strings of letters**

```
Clear[abcToNum]
abcToNum[s_String] := 
  FromDigits@ToUpperCase@Characters[s] /. reverseNumRules;

numDictQ[abcToNum["phone spell"]] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]